# Developing a C++ program on linux using two threads, always keeping one thread running

Tags: c++, multithreading, productivity, memory, speed

The title describes an idea of a solution to a more general problem. Here is the general problem:

I am developing a program which looks roughly as follows:

[read a lot of data, store in data structure X]
[do complex operations on X]
.

The reading is easy to develop, but running it takes a lot of time. The second part needs development and experimentation. So I want to recompile and run the second part many times.

What is a *nice* way of achieving this?

(Here are some conditions I put on being nice: *not depending on a lot of libraries *minimal overhead in execution time * not depending on details of X *as general as possible (maybe not even limited to C++ or linux))

Here is the idea for a solution I have in mind: We let one thread of a process do the reading, and the other thread do everything else. Since memory is shared between threads, the second thread can read from X, which has been created by the first thread.

I don't know if this is feasible, since I don't know if one can easily 'restart'/'join' a thread. But the general problem seems general enough that someone else probably has solved it.

Comment: Take a öook at [`std:condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable).

Comment: If you always want to have only one thread running, what's the point of having two of them? Why not simply alternate between the two tasks normally?

Comment: You probably want [data baking](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/132376/delicious_data_baking.php)

Comment: You cannot recompile one thread's code without stopping your whole application. I don't see how your solution accomplishes your goal.

Answer (score 3):

> The reading is easy to develop, but running it takes a lot of time. The second part needs development and experimentation. So I want to recompile and run the second part many times.

In this case, multiple threads is unlikely to solve your problem.

To automatically share memory between threads, they all belong to the same process. And that is where the problems start, because it ranges from difficult to impossible to replace parts of the code of a running process without killing that process.

If all your data fits into memory, then you can write the reading and processing code as separate applications, using the linux shared-memory inter process communication to share the data structure X.

Another possibility would be to look into the use of memory-mapped files.

If there is too much data to fit into memory and memory-mapped files also don't work, then your wish to keep the reading part running while you replace the processing part is asking for more trouble, as the processing part will then always miss the first part of the data that was read (as it was invariably already processed by an earlier version of the processing part) and you need to add logic for synchronizing the processing code with the data stream coming from the reading part.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is feasible, but... there is a risk of data race on X.

Some more details:

- C++ comes with a [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) that fully supports multithreading in a portable way.
- The general approach to your problem is the [producer/consumer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  The producer reads the data and stores it in X.  The consumer(s) process data in X.
- The problem is that X being written and read by concurrent threads, there is a risk of [data race](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model), which is undefined behavior in C++.
- A popular way of solving this is to put X in slices into a queue:  The producer enqueues X items to be processed;  The consumer(s) dequeues the X items and processes them.  When the queue is empty,  the consumer waits until something new comes (or until it receives a command on the queue that tells it to stop).
  The queue can be implemented as a [lock free list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_linked_list).
- If lock-free queue is not an option, you may prevent data races using atomics, or protecting the data structure with locks (e.g. [mutex](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/producer-consumer-problem-using-semaphores-set-1/)) .  You can also avoid the consumer running idle constantly looking for new data, using a [condition variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to "wake up" the consumers with a kind of notification.  Unfortunately, all these mechanisms bear the risk of reducing the amount of real concurrency that you can expect.

The topic of concurrency looks simple but in reality is awfully complex. There are full books to introduce the concepts, such as for example the excellent "*C++ Concurrency in Action*" by Anthony Williams. I will not compete against it with my little answer here.

But the main issue that you will face will not be how to use threads and detach them, but how to avoid that two threads access the same data, one of them being writing it (fortunately also addressed in William's book).